# Lost the data I moved to an external drive on Windows

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive

This happened to me twice so far. I have 2 Windows PCs with an external drive attached to one of them (Windows 11 Pro). It is a 3TB HDD that is about 25% full. Yesterday, I switched off the Windows 11 PC, attached the drive to the other PC (Windows 10 Pro), and started the latter.

Everything is normal so far. So, I proceeded to move my Steam library folder (about 240GB) to the drive. It took a while (copying from HDD to another) but it completed without anything obviously not right (I can see the files already moved to the HDD).

I switched off the Windows 10 PC, attached the drive to the Windows 11 PC, and started the latter.
When I opened the HDD, I did not see the files that I just copied.

My questions are:

- Why did this happen?
- How to prevent something like this from happening in the future (this happened to me twice)?
- How to restore the "lost files" (not huge importance, it is just Steam library)?

Additional context

I mentioned that this happened to me twice. The first time I actually lost some personal pictures. It happened something like this:

- I had a 16GB thumb drive that was plugged to a PC that was asleep (not shutdown).
- I unplugged the thumb drive and plugged it to my laptop.
- I moved a folder or 2 which contain about 2GB of pictures (between RAW and JPEG) to the thumb drive.
- I either safely remove the drive or shutdown the laptop (I do not remember; that was more than a year ago).
- I plugged the thumb drive to the PC and woke it up.
- The folders are not there.

Comment: Why would you back up (or restore) your Steam library folder? You can just download em again.

Comment: Do you have Fast Startup enabled on either of these PCs? // Also, changing hardware, especially involving filesystems, while a system is suspended or hibernating is a big no-no.

Comment: @Gantendo, thanks for the suggestion, but this beyond the point. My question is about losing data in the scenario I mentioned, not about backing up Steam library. I also lost pictures that I took in the past because of this.

Comment: @DanielB, Yes, I had Fast Startup on, but now I turned it off.

Comment: "Why did this happen?" - Begging for speculation and also comparing two *seemingly* cases that may be very unrelated. USB flash drives are notoriously unreliable for example. I am voting close. Needs focus and less inviting for speculation.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, have you had the chance to read my answer? This is not as speculative as you may think and the 2 cases turned out to be related to the same issue. You have the right to choose to vote for closing this, but your reasoning is a bit weird. Beside, investigating this case help me to understand the issue, recover the data, and be aware not to "fall into this trap in the future". I am sure it can, and most likely will, help other people too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: That still doesn't solve the 'focus' issue, plus one could argue since you found the answer elsewhere that this is a duplicate. As it is, it is a bad question.

Comment: @music2myear, no it does not. But thanks for the comment. I already answered this question with the solution that worked with me for this specific situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue is with default shutdown behaviour since Window 8 or 8.1. Thanks to user1574981 for their answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1202885/43291).

Also, thanks to Daniel B for [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1819168/lost-the-data-i-moved-to-an-external-drive-on-windows/1819174#comment2862470_1819168) comment.

#### More details

Starting with Windows 8, the default behaviour of the shutdown option changed to a hybrid shutdown, which is sometimes referred to as "fast start-up". This feature combines aspects of traditional shutdown and hibernation.

When you select "Shutdown" in Windows 8.1 or newer, the operating system saves the current state of the system into a hibernation file (hiberfil.sys). This allows the system to start up more quickly the next time you power it on. The hybrid shutdown is designed to improve the start-up time by partially hibernating the system instead of performing a complete shutdown and subsequent full boot.

Because of this, the HDD was not unmounted and caused the behaviour I saw. More details on why is that in user1574981's answer that I referred to earlier.

#### What about the data?

The data was not visible even when connecting the HDD back to the Windows 10 PC. So, I performed disk checking and repairing on the Windows 10 PC and I was able to get the data back.

I then did "safe removal" for the HDD and connected it to the Windows 11 PC. Now I can see the data there as well.

#### One more thing

I also disabled "fast start-up" (Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\System Settings).

Answer (score 2):

Best guess is the drive was not correctly unmounted, the writes had not been correctly flushed through.
A sleeping machine still has the drives mounted. One shut down *should* have correctly dismounted them first. Disconnecting whilst still mounted allows for the possibility of this write error. This is also more likely if you used cut & paste, rather than copy/paste/manual delete. It's always safer to test you have two copies, than *hope* you have one.

Do you use ExFAT for these drives? [That's the format most drives arrive as, when new.] If so, it would be far better to use NTFS, or any properly journaled file system your machine can read & write, as these are designed to try to eliminate this failure on accidental disconnect.

ExFAT may be a *portable* disk format, but it's a poor one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Tetsujin. My 3TB HDD is NTFS. I also found the problem and the solution. Please, check my answer.